# Creating Collapsible Bootstrap Sidebars with jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have using the following example for the collapsible sidebar, in this case, the sidebar should be initially collapsed how to do that I have tried but was not able to do it properly please anyone help me on this.
Thanks in Advance
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-Collapsible-Bootstrap-Sidebars-with-jQuery-CSS/

Answer (score 1):

add the `collapsed` html class to the sidebar container

Comment: if i add collpased left side bar will collpased but right side bar will not be

Comment: on this example page the right sidebar (collapsed) has those styles: `@media (min-width: 992px)
(index):63
#sidebar-right.collapsed {
    margin-right: -25%;
}`, so check if you have the right id and styles set

Answer (score 0):

class="panel-collapse collapse"